# Extending boot partition on OpenMediaVault/Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, debian, lvm

I've just resized the Virtual Space on VirtualBox image 2G to 8G. But how can I expand the main boot partition without reinstalling the server?
[GParted screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO3vN.png)

lsblk command:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0   10G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0   10G  0 part /srv/dev-disk-by-label-Shared
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
sda      8:0    0    8G  0 disk
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0  135M  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1   8:1    0  1,9G  0 part /
```

fdisk -l command:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x78430124

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048 3913727 3911680  1,9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       3915774 4192255  276482  135M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       3915776 4192255  276480  135M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

I tried to do this with this command:

```
lvm lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/sda1
```

But gives error message:

```
Path required for Logical Volume "sda1"
Please provide a volume group name
Run lvextend --help for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use lvm to extend partitions. You should use (g)parted, or other partitioning tools. There is an extended partition right after sda1. But it is used only for swap, so you could remove it, extend sda1, and then add the swap partition back.